# How to search[re] and skip to text in the next line using re in python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I have a string in python where I need to go to the next line of characters, put it in a List and split with a comma. I am very close to having a solution using different regex combinations. However, I have spent days figuring this out and just couldn't find the correct regex or make one. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the String format :

```
Roles
Administrator,User,Auditor,Console
```

So far, I have tried the following in python IDE (for practice purpose only):

```
>>> line: """roles
Administrator,Console,User"""
>>> r2 = re.findall(r'\n^[A-Z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]', line, re.MULTILINE)
>>> print(r2)
['\nAdministrator']
```

Here is the actual code in my pycharm file:

```py
    def dashboardroles(self):  
        pagecontent = self.driver.find_element(*Elements.mainpage)
        content = pagecontent.text
        actual = content.split('\n')
        for line in actual:
            if re.search("Roles", line):
                lines = line
                role = lines.split(" ")
                roles = [i.strip(',') for i in role]
                return roles

>>> print(dashboardroles)
```

With the above code, I am getting the following output:

```
['Roles']
```

Expected output: 
I need to A)Skip the word 'roles' B) move to the next line C) print the entire line similar to the following:

```
['Administrator', 'User', 'Auditor', 'Console']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer for the above code is the following:

```
def dashboardroles(self):
    pagecontent = self.driver.find_element(*Elements.mainpage)
    content = pagecontent.text
    actual = content.split('\n')
    found = False
    for line in actual:
        if found:
            roles = line.split(",")
            return roles
        if re.search("Roles", line):
            found = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% aware of what you want but if you just need to find the line after Roles no regrex is needed...using a flag like this would work

```
page = '''garbage111
Roles
Administrator,Console,User
garbage222
'''
has_roles = False
roles = []
for line in page.split('\n'):
    if has_roles:
        roles = list(line.split(","))
        break
    if line.strip() == "Roles":
        has_roles = True
        #go to the next line with flag set
print(roles)
```

prints `['Administrator', 'Console', 'User']`

if you need to use regrex/dont want to loop over each line you could use something like this

```
import re

page = '''garbage111
Roles
Administrator,Console,User
garbage222
'''
line = re.search(r"^Roles\n(.*)",page, re.MULTILINE).group(1)
roles = list(line.split(','))
print(roles)
```

prints `['Administrator', 'Console', 'User']`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have realized that I didn't need the regex for the logic. One of my colleagues suggested a solution that worked (very similar to your answer). I will update my initial question with the correct answer.